# I want to create a matrix of five columns out of an nxm matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a big matrix with more than 100 columns, but not all of them have values ONLY 5 or 6 consecutive columns have values in each row and the rest are NAs. I want to create a matrix has only 5 columns that taking the values of the 5 consecutive columns. For example:

A = [NA NA 1 2 3 4 5 6 NA NA; 1 2 3 4 5 NA NA NA NA NA; NA NA NA NA 1 2 3 4 5 6; NA NA NA 1 2 3 4 5 NA NA]

I want this matrix:

A = [1 2 3 4 5; 1 2 3 4 5; 1 2 3 4 5; 1 2 3 4 5]

Thank you

Comment: You should show what you've tried so far if you want to get meaningful help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#DATA
A = structure(c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 3L, NA, NA, 2L, 
4L, NA, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, NA, 2L, 3L, 5L, NA, 3L, 4L, 6L, 
NA, 4L, 5L, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 6L, NA), .Dim = c(4L, 10L
))

#INPUT
A
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]   NA   NA    1    2    3    4    5    6   NA    NA
#[2,]    1    2    3    4    5   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    1    2    3    4    5     6
#[4,]   NA   NA   NA    1    2    3    4    5   NA    NA
```

The straightforward way is be to go through each row (using `lapply` or `apply`) and extract the first 5 non NA elements from each row.

```
A_out = do.call(rbind, lapply(1:NROW(A), function(i) A[i,][!is.na(A[i,])][1:5]))
```

OR

```
A_out = t(apply(X = A, MARGIN = 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1:5]))

#OUTPUT
A_out
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[3,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[4,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts,this works perfectly fine for the example that I gave. I have another example, which is a bit different, and wonder how to do the same think! For instance if one of the row is like this: A[1,] = [NA 7 NA 9 NA 1 2 3 4 5], how can I get only [1 2 3 4 5] and ignoring 7 and 9? So I want to extract ONLY when there is a continues 5 numbers without any gap between the numbers! Many thanks